# TSQL get unique (not overlapping) datetime ranges

Tags: t-sql, datetime, overlapping

This is a question like this: [TSQL get overlapping periods from datetime ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873116/tsql-get-overlapping-periods-from-datetime-ranges) but with a different result request.

This is the table:

```
create table period (
    id int,
    starttime datetime,
    endtime datetime,
    type varchar(64)
  );

insert into period values (1,'2013-04-07 8:00','2013-04-07 13:00','Work');
insert into period values (2,'2013-04-07 14:00','2013-04-07 17:00','Work');
insert into period values (3,'2013-04-08 8:00','2013-04-08 13:00','Work');
insert into period values (4,'2013-04-08 14:00','2013-04-08 17:00','Work');
insert into period values (5,'2013-04-07 10:00','2013-04-07 11:00','Holyday'); /* 1h overlapping with 1*/
insert into period values (6,'2013-04-08 10:00','2013-04-08 20:00','Transfer'); /* 6h overlapping with 3 and 4*/
insert into period values (7,'2013-04-08 11:00','2013-04-08 12:00','Test');  /* 1h overlapping with 3 and 6*/
```

I need the **unique not overlapping** datetime ranges table.

In the before example the result would be:

```
'2013-04-07 08:00','2013-04-07 13:00'
'2013-04-07 14:00','2013-04-07 17:00'
'2013-04-08 08:00','2013-04-08 20:00'
```

It is not very important if could be time fragmentation such as:

```
'2013-04-08 08:00','2013-04-08 13:00'
'2013-04-08 12:00','2013-04-08 20:00'
```

**--EDIT--**

Another example:

```
create table period (
    id int,
    starttime datetime,
    endtime datetime,
    type varchar(64)
  );

insert into period values (1,'2013-06-13 8:30','2013-06-13 12:30','');
insert into period values (2,'2013-06-13 8:38','2013-06-13 12:38','');
insert into period values (3,'2013-06-13 13:18','2013-06-13 17:45','');
insert into period values (4,'2013-06-13 13:30','2013-06-13 17:30','');
insert into period values (5,'2013-06-13 20:00','2013-06-13 23:59','');
```

this should return:

2013-06-13 08:30 - 2013-06-13 12:38

2013-06-13 13:18 - 2013-06-13 17:45

2013-06-13 20:00 - 2013-06-13 23:59

Answer (score 2):

But you have only one non-overlapping period, or did I understand the question wrong?

```
select * 
from period t
where id in (
select t1.id
from period t1 
join period t2 on t1.id <> t2.id
where t2.endtime <= t1.starttime or t2.starttime >= t1.endtime
group by t1.id
having count(*) + 1 = (select count(*) from period)
)
```

Result:

```
'2013-04-07 14:00','2013-04-07 17:00'
```

**Update**: Ok, so you want to merge overlapping ranges. Try this:

```
select starttime, endtime 
from period 
where id in (
select t1.id
from period t1 
join period t2 on t1.id <> t2.id
where t2.endtime < t1.starttime or t2.starttime > t1.endtime
group by t1.id
having count(*) + 1 = (select count(*) from period)
) 

union all

select min(start), max(fin) from (
select 
case when t2.starttime < t1.starttime then t2.starttime else t1.starttime end as start,
case when t2.endtime < t1.endtime then t1.endtime else t2.endtime end as fin
from period t1 
join period t2 on t1.id < t2.id
where t2.endtime >= t1.starttime and t2.starttime <= t1.endtime) overlaps
group by datepart(dd, start), datepart(dd, fin)
```

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear, I don't need the not overlapping from given table, but the union set of the given table without overlapping ranges (for example these rows: 08:00-10:00 and 09:00-11:00 became 08:00-11:00 or with fragmentation 08:00-10:00 and 10:00-11:00).

Comment: There is a little mistake when I add a non overlapping range but consecutive, se here (la insert causes the mistake): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ecc46/1

Comment: There is a bug in this solution, please check my 2nd example in question.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution... I think this is not the best way, but seems to work.

```
DECLARE @union_unique TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key ,starttime datetime,endtime datetime)
DECLARE @idset TABLE (id int)

DECLARE @i int


SET @i = 1
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM period) > 0
    WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM period))
       BEGIN

          delete from @idset
          insert into @idset
          select distinct t2.id
          from period t1
          join @union_unique t2 on convert(date, t1.starttime)=convert(date, t2.starttime)
          where t1.id=@i and
          (
            t1.starttime >= t2.starttime and t1.starttime <= t2.endtime 
            or
            t1.endtime >= t2.starttime and t1.endtime <= t2.endtime 
            or
            t1.starttime <= t2.starttime and t1.endtime >= t2.endtime 
           )



          if(select count(*) from @idset)=0
            insert into @union_unique (starttime, endtime) select starttime, endtime from period where id=@i
          else
            BEGIN


              insert into @union_unique (starttime, endtime)
                select 
                    min(starttime),
                    max(endtime)
                from (
                    select starttime, endtime from @union_unique where id in (select id from @idset)
                    union 
                    select starttime, endtime from period where id=@i
                ) alll

              delete from @union_unique where id in (select id from @idset)

            END

          SET @i = @i + 1


    END


select * from @union_unique order by starttime
```